# How do I use celery and django to run tasks that are already in a rabbitmq queue?

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

At this point I have read most of the rabbitmq documentation and the celery documentation, and google soo many times. Essentially I can't find anywhere the information that I'm needing.

I have a twisted webserver reading messages passed to it, and putting the message into a queue using pika. That works fine. The problem I am having is what I do from here. What will happen is that periodically (using celerybeat) I want to consume what is currently in the queue. The big problem I am having is that I have no idea how to pass tasks into rabbitmq so that celery (or celerybeat) can assign the tasks to be completed.

The easiest way to ask this question is: Can I read queues which have data as the body and use that data in django?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is of any help, but i use djcelery for task queueing from django, this queues to rabbit mq

a seperate python manage.py (celeryd|celerybeat) process picks up queued tasks based on settings in django

https://github.com/ask/django-celery

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I have the same question, but let me restate it to be sure:

Can you use Celery to consume messages that were put into RabbitMQ by another non-Django, non-Celery process? For example, if a Java system sends a message to RabbitMQ when a purchase is made can a Celery task respond to that message and take some action?